# How to access a specific value in a mixed object(stdClass) and array construct?

Tags: php

My variable looks like this:

```
var_dump($content)

object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
      ["message"]=>
      string(24) "Invalid or expired token"
      ["code"]=>
      int(89)
    }
  }
}
```

How can a get the value of `message` ("Invalid or expired token")?

Comment: OK, I've edited your question into shape and added a hopefully canonical answer. This question pops up again and again every day. Hope this will be the canonical entry which we can close other duplicate questions against. Please don't feel that it's welcome to ask such basic questions, you should really figure out such simple things using the manual or Google. However, since it is a common problem that people do not do so, let's let this one stand here for all to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a value says `object(stdClass)` in a `var_dump`, you access its properties with the `->` notation. So the first step in your case is:

```
$content->errors
```

This now is an array, so you access its keys using `[..]` notation. The next step down is:

```
$content->errors[0]
```

This now again is a `object(stdClass)`, so you access its properties using `->`:

```
$content->errors[0]->message
```

However, this structure implies that there may be multiple errors. You should rather loop through the `errors` array and output all errors in turn:

```
foreach ($content->errors as $error) {
    echo $error->message;
}
```

Comment: You might want to buld a string in the foreach instead of just echoing, that will give you the ability to work with the string more.

Comment: @Brett You may want to take a number of actions based on the actual errors in that array, not just echo them.

Comment: Agreed, that structure also gives @user3128221 access to the error code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to iterate and you can access the message var directly:

```
<?php

foreach ($content->errors as $item)
{
   echo $item->message;
}
```

Comment: was in a hurry, my bad